# Ajax auto fill input fields and image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

The code below auto fills the Full name and Email when the user enters their ID. I also want to display the user's image but i'm having issues.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#techid" ).on( 'blur' , function() {
            searchString = $(this).val();
            var data = 'telefoon='+searchString;
            if(searchString) {
                $.ajax({
                    type    : "POST",
                    url     : "query2.php",
                    data    : data,
                    success : function(html){ 
                        result = String(html).split("|");
                        $("#name").val(result[0]);
                        $("#mail").val(result[1]);
                        $("#avatar").val(result[2]);
                    }
                });    
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
 </script>
```

I know I can display the image like this but how do i integrate it with the AJAX?

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
    include_once("connection.php");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players3");
    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {      
        echo '<img height="80px" width="100px"  src="data:image/jpeg;    base64,'.base64_encode( $res['image'] ).'"/>';

?>
```

I tried this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="telefoon" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Avatar</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <img height="80px" width="100px" id="avatar" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( )"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="telefoon" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tech ID</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="techid" class="form-control" id="techid" placeholder="TechID" >
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="naam" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="mail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="mail" class="form-control" id="mail" placeholder="email">
    </div>
</div>
```

Like this?

```
 <?php

 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
 include_once("connection-db2.php");
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TechID");

 while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {     


 echo '<li><img height="80px" width="100px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $res['image'] ).'"/>';
 }
 ?>
```

JS

```
$("#image").attr('src', result[4]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. when upload the image, save the image path with image file name. like "images/image1.jpg"
2. like the name and email, query the path of the image.
3. make a empty
4. after ajax success you get the path of the image. right? use this path like this. $("#image_to_show").html("");

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` tag [doesn't have `value` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)
You should probably `echo` just image url and set it as a `src` attribute of your `img` tag

PHP:

```
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo $res['image'];
    // ...
}
```

JS:

```
$("#avatar").attr('src', result[2]);
```

---

On a side note - it would be better to [**`json_encode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) response and use it instead of `.split("|")`. Something like this:

PHP:

```
$response = array();
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $response['name'] = $res['name'];
    $response['email'] = $res['email'];
    $response['image'] = $res['image'];
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type     : "POST",
    url      : "query2.php",
    data     : data,
    dataType : "json",
    success  : function(result){ 
        $("#name").val(result.name);
        $("#mail").val(result.email);
        $("#avatar").attr('src', result.image);
    }
});
```